# output to html results in JSON format clean

Tags: python, json, django, python-3.x, executable

I have a django app that is executing some python scripts and returning results to webpage .... unfortunately the results that are in JSON format look nasty as hell and hard to read .. I am using Visual Studio Code and using the Terminal in that the JSON output is lovely and nice to read which is not good for this .... Anyone know a way to present the results in nice standard JSON Format on my webpage

```
from django.shortcuts import render
import requests
import sys
from subprocess import run, PIPE

def button(request):
    return render(request,'homepage.html')

def external(request):
 out=run([sys.executable,'//home//testuser//data-extract.py'],shell=False,stdout=PIPE)
json.dumps(out, indent=4, sort_keys=True)
    print(out)
    return render(request,'homepage.html',{'data':out})
```

Comment: `json.dumps(out, indent=4, sort_keys=True)` formats JSON data 'lovely'.

Comment: hum now its throwing an error 

Object of type 'CompletedProcess' is not JSON serializable

Answer (score 0):

try to do this at frontend side

html

```
<pre id="json"></pre>
```

javascript

```js
var data = {
    "data": {
      "study":"mca"
    },
    "name": "l.b.vasoya",
    "country": "india",
    "id": 50
}
document.getElementById("json").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(data,undefined,2)
```

```html
<pre id='json'></pre>
```

```
document.getElementById("json").innerHTML = JSON.stringify({{ data }}, undefined, 2);
```

go through this link 
[JSON.stringify use](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-pretty-print-json-string-in-javascript/)
try and let me know